# Pass null as parameter in Regex.Replace

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, mailmerge

I want to replace value from sql database in mail merging. But I seem to be getting an error message in visual studio.

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: replacement

when I try this

```
Regex.Replace(mergeFieldsXML.InnerXml,"«[^»]*" + wordtoReplace + "[^»]*»", SecurityElement.Escape(mailMergeData[wordtoReplace ]),RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I am wondering if it is possible to ignore the null value and continue with the replacement?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31395730/edit) your question and replace each word “it” with the specific thing you are talking about.

Comment: Maybe `mailMergeData[key] == null ? "" : mailMergeData[key]` or some other way to identify if `key` exists.

Comment: I tried Maybe mailMergeData[key] == null ? "" : mailMergeData[key] and one of the keys is null value. Is there anyway I can continue even with the null.

Comment: One of the keys is null? Meaning that `wordtoReplace` might itself be null? In that case, we would need to know exactly what `mailMergeData` is (dictionary? custom class with indexed property?). In any case, that's not what the error you're getting means, the error implies that `mailMergeData[wordToReplace]` is returning null, so sln's suggestion of the ternary operator should work (though I'd personally prefer the null coalescing operator because it's more succinct: `mailMergeData[wordtoReplace] ?? string.Empty`)

Answer (score 2):

Not it is not possible to ignore the null value and continue. If you look at the [documentation for the method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f(v=vs.110).aspx) it clearly states that you will get a `ArgumentNullException` if any of input, pattern, or replacement is null.

You can either do a null check on those values before calling the method or using the null-coalescing operator `??` inline.